# How can access inner elements of NavigationLink in accessibility in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, accessibility

I have enabled accessibility for automation testing. I have added accessibility label for all element but accessible of elements inside the NavigationLink is false.

```
   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
         List(todoItems) { todoItem in
            NavigationLink(destination: TodoDetailView(todoItem: todoItem)) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                        .accessibilityLabel(Text("heart.fill"))
                    VStack {
                        Text(todoItem.action + "1")
                            .accessibilityLabel(Text(todoItem.action + "3"))
                        Text(todoItem.action + "2")
                            .accessibilityLabel(Text(todoItem.action + "4"))
                    }
                }
            }
            .accessibilityElement(children: .contain)
         }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Todo Items"))
      }
   }
```

[image]

Not able to access image in accessibility

I am try to access individual items of NavigationLink in accessibility

Answer (score 0):

I changed your View and added a accessibility label for the `NavigationLink` like this:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List(todoItems) { todoItem in
        NavigationLink(destination: TodoDetailView(todoItem: todoItem)) {
          HStack {
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
              .accessibilityLabel(Text("heart.fill"))
            VStack {
              Text(todoItem.action + "1")
                .accessibilityLabel(Text(todoItem.action + "3"))
              Text(todoItem.action + "2")
                .accessibilityLabel(Text(todoItem.action + "4"))
            }
          }
        }
        .accessibilityElement(children: .contain)
        .accessibilityLabel("navigationLink")
      }
      .navigationBarTitle(Text("Todo Items"))
    }
  }
```

Then you are able to access the Navigation Link in your UI Tests like this:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()
let navigationLink = app.otherElements["navigationLink"]
```

The `Image` can also be accessed via the `NavigationLink` element:

```
let image = navigationLink.images["heart.fill"]
```

I tested it and I was able to find the elements in the tests and could assert the existence